# How to use hooks as image's source in react native?

Tags: react-native, image, react-hooks

Im making this menu that when the user clicks at an option, it changes the background image, but i cant use the hook that i created as a parameter to the source of the image. Can someone find where im wrong and how to fix it?
Heres the part of my code referents to the menu and the hooks:

```
export function Home(){
    let imagens = {
        vovo: '../assets/vovoJuju.png',
        mc: '../assets/mcJuju.png',
        pato: '../assets/patoJuju.png',
    }
    const navigation = useNavigation<any>();
    const [showBottomSheet, setShowBottomSheet] = React.useState(false);
    const [param, setParam] = useState(1);
    const [skin, setSkin] = useState('vovo')
     const hide = () => {
        setShowBottomSheet(false)
    }
    function handleAbout(){
        navigation.navigate('About');
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(param==1){
            setSkin('vovo');
        }
        else if(param==2){
            setSkin('mc');
        }
        else if(param==3){
            setSkin('pato');
        }
    })
 
    return(
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleAbout}>
                <Counter />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            setShowBottomSheet(true)
          }}
            >
                <Image source={skin} style={styles.imgvj}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <BottomSheet show={showBottomSheet} height={290} onOuterClick={hide}>
                <Pressable onPress={hide} style={styles.bottomSheetContent}>
                    <Image source={barrinhaLoja} style={styles.barra}/>
                    </Pressable>
                <View style={styles.conteudoLoja}>
                    <View style={styles.marginLeft48}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                            setParam(1);
                            }}>
                            <Image source={vovoJuju} style={styles.vovo}/>
                            <Text style={styles.legendasLoja}>Vovó Juju</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                    <View>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                            setParam(2);
                            }}>
                            <Image source={mcJuju} style={styles.mc}/>
                            <Text style={styles.legendasLoja}>MC Juju</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                        
                    <View>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                            setParam(3);
                            }}>
                            <Image source={patoJuju} style={styles.pato}/>
                            <Text style={styles.legendasLoja}>Pato Juju</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                </View>
            </BottomSheet>
```

I created the "let imagens", "const param", "const skin" and the "useEffect trying" to make this function. I already tried using the source in different ways such as source={skin} and source={imagens[skin]} but it havent worked.

Comment: You definitely don't need useEffect for this, and `skin` can be a regular variable. No need for useState.

Comment: @Evert , If possible can you show how it would be done without it? I cant see how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain if this solves your problem, but here's how the first few lines of your component should look like without `useEffect`:

```js
const imagens = {
  vovo: '../assets/vovoJuju.png',
  mc: '../assets/mcJuju.png',
  pato: '../assets/patoJuju.png',
};

export function Home(){

    const navigation = useNavigation<any>();
    const [showBottomSheet, setShowBottomSheet] = React.useState(false);
    const [param, setParam] = useState(1);
    const hide = () => {
      setShowBottomSheet(false)
    }
    function handleAbout(){
        navigation.navigate('About');
    }
    
    let skin = 'vovo';
    switch(param) {
       case 1: skin = 'vovo'; break;
       case 2: skin = 'mc'; break;
       case 3: skin = 'pato'; break;
    } 
    return /* the rest goes here */
    
}
```

To reference the actual image, you would use something like `{imagens[skin]}`.

I moved `imagens` outside of this function because it never changes, but it doesn't impact anything otherwise.

Comment: I tried it but it just goes blank instead of showing the image. But thank you anyway for the attention and for your point of view!

Comment: "skin" in <Image source={images[skin]} style={styles.imgvj}/> is getting error "type 'undefined' cannot be used as an idex type", i think this may be the error

Comment: @Lucca in that code you use `images` but in your original code you use `imagens`

Comment: Yeah ive made that spelling change but the error was there before as well

Comment: @Lucca I made a change that might fix that problem.

Comment: Its the type of "skin"? As ive looked it up here if i somehow dont allow it to be undefined it may work

Comment: @Lucca i don't know what happened but somehow my change got lost. Updated for real now. Typescript thought that skin might be undefined or a string.

Comment: i did your change but it lead me to another error, then i added this ":any" in "const images: any = {" and id didnt show any other error, but still theres a blank where it should be showing the image :x , but at least the error alert is gone haha

Comment: @Lucca it's gonna be difficult to walk you through every error and give you the solution. Best thing I can recommend is taking some time to understand what Typescript is telling you or until then lots of `any` and `console.log` until you get there ;)  good luck!

Comment: Sure, i got to make it work now: in the `const images: any ={` instead of asigning the variables to the adress of the image as it was `vovo: '../assets/vovoJuju.png', ` for example, i wrote it like `vovo: vovoJuju,` instead, as i had already asigned vovoJuju to the address of the image in the imports. Just leaving it here in case this helps someone in the future. Thank you very much @Evert for your attention and your help!